# The convergence set of a sequence of functions can be expressed in terms of upper and lower envelopes

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

let $f_n:\mathbb R\to[0,\infty)$ be a sequence of functions. Its lower envelope sequences are defined as $\underline{f_n}(x)=\inf\{f_k(x):k\geq n\}$. And its upper envelope is defined similarly except that it's in terms of sup. Is it true that the set where $f_n$ converges precisely the set where $\{x:\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(\underline{f_n}-\overline{f_n})=0\}$?

This seems trivial but I did not see such a theorem or whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will define the upper and lower envelopes as $u_n$ and $l_n$ of $f_n$ for simplicity.  Note that for each $x$, both $u_n(x)$ and $l_n(x)$ are monotonic, respectively decreasing and increasing. Their almost sure limits exist and equal $\limsup_n f_n(x)$ and $\liminf_n f_n(x)$. A sequence of real numbers converges if and only if its limsup and liminf are equal, so
$$\{x : f_n(x)\text{ converges}\} = \{x : \limsup_n f_n(x) = \liminf_n f_n(x)\}.$$
Since we already have $l_n(x) \leqslant u_n(x)$ for all $n$ by definition,  $\{x : \lim_n u_n(x) \leqslant \lim_n l_n(x)\} = \{x : \limsup_n f_n(x) = \liminf_n f_n(x)\}$ is precisely the set where $f_n$ converges.

Comment: If we know that the sequence is bounded, can we get the conclusion that the lower envelope converges pointwise to some function? Since it is monotone and bounded?

Comment: You only need bounded from above for convergence of the lower envelope $l_n(x) = \inf_{k \geq n} f_k(x)$, though if you allow $-\infty$, $\lim_n l_n$ always exists. Same with $+\infty$ for $\lim_n u_n$.